# Is there is any way to drop/hide system extended stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, mcafee, extended-procedures

After running  McAfee ePolicy Orchestrator 5.1.0 report for our DB (SQL Server 2008R2) got a bunch of items of the next view:

> The stored procedure xp_xxx is enabled. It is recommended to drop it
>   if not needed.

We've checked and all these *xp_xxx* SPs are belongs to sys. Tried next thing:

```
EXEC sys.xp_sqlagent_is_starting
```

Result:

> Msg 22024, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Usage:  EXECUTE
>   xp_sqlagent_is_starting <Flag INT> OUTPUT

So such SP present. Then tried:

```
exec sp_dropextendedproc xp_sqlagent_is_starting
```

AND

```
DROP PROCEDURE xp_sqlagent_is_starting
```

Result:

> Msg 3701, Level 16, State 15, Procedure sp_dropextendedproc, Line 18
>   Cannot drop the procedure 'xp_sqlagent_is_starting', because it does
>   not exist or you do not have permission.

AND

> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1 Cannot drop the procedure
>   'xp_sqlagent_is_starting', because it does not exist or you do not
>   have permission.

All attemps under 'sa' user. It's obvious for me that there is no way to drop them and frankly speaking I don't see security issues in them. But the report should be clean :(
The question is:

- Is there is any way to DROP sys. extended SP?
- Or maybe to HIDE them for the user/role under which McAfee ePolicy
  Orchestrator 5.1.0 is running its scan?

  I need to remove that messages from the security report. 
  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot drop system extended procedures. Don't try to drop them, just take away execute permission for everyone:

```
DENY EXECUTE ON xp_xxx TO PUBLIC;
```

Other XPs can be dropped, but may break your applications if they're used.